# Is solution multiplying Fourier transforms for product of two sequences wrong?

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, signal-processing

Consider the sequence

$$
r[n] =   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1, & 0\leq n\leq M \\
      0, & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

for which

$$
R(e^{j\omega}) = e^{-j\frac{M}{2}\omega}\times\frac{ sin(\frac{M+1}{2} \omega) } {sin(\frac{\omega}{2})}
$$

Find the Fourier transform of the following sequence in terms of $R(e^{j\omega})$:

$$
w[n] = \left\{
\begin{array}
(\frac{1}{2}[1 - cos(\frac{2\pi n}{M})], & 0\leq n\leq M \\
0, & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

**Solution that I think is wrong**:

Since,
$$
w[n] = r[n] \cdot \frac{1}{2}[1+cos(\frac{2\pi n}{M})]
$$

$$
W(e^{j\omega}) = R(e^{j\omega})\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}(1+cos(2\pi n/M))(e^{-j\omega n}) \\
= R(e^{j\omega})\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}e^{j2\pi n/M}+\frac{1}{4}e^{-j2\pi n/M})e^{-j\omega n} \\
= R(e^{j\omega})\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2}\delta(\omega)+\frac{1}{4}\delta(\omega+2\pi /M)+\frac{1}{4}\delta(\omega-2\pi /M)) \\
$$

I think this solution is wrong **because the Fourier transform of the product of two sequence is not the product of their respective Fourier transforms**. Rather, it is the periodic convolution of their respective Fourier transforms.

Moreover, the sum $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-j\omega n}$ does not converge. The Fourier transform for $x[n]=1$ is not derived from that sum, and also is $2\pi \delta(\omega)$ not $\delta(\omega)$ as used above.

**My solution:**

From the modulation/windowing theorem,

$$
W(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}R(e^{j\omega})\cdot 2\pi(\frac{1}{2}\delta(\omega - \theta)+\frac{1}{4}\delta(\omega-\theta+\frac{2\pi}{M})+\frac{1}{4}\delta(\omega - \theta\ + \frac{2\pi}{M})) d\theta \\
= \frac{1}{2}R(e^{j\omega}) + \frac{1}{4}R(e^{j(\omega-2\pi/M)})+\frac{1}{4}R(e^{j(\omega+2\pi/M)})
$$

---

Is my reasoning for why the first solution is wrong, correct? Is my solution correct?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: apparently there is a typo in the first solution, the multiplication between the two Fourier transforms should be convolution. Performing the convolution between the two sequences in the last equation of the first solution gives the same result as the second solution.

Comment: @Stelios I think the first is wrong because of the steps used in it are logically are wrong (multiplication of Fourier transforms instead of convolution). The first solution was found in a solutions paper for my book.

I think you're making the same point as I did in the question. This question was to confirm my analysis.

Comment: Yes, the steps in the first solution are definitely sloppy. Your solution is correct. I would simply write $W(e^{j\omega})=R(e^{j\omega}) * \left[\frac{1}{2}\delta(\omega) + \frac{1}{4} \delta(\omega+2\pi/M)  + \frac{1}{4} \delta(\omega-2\pi/M)  \right]$ , where '$*$' is the convolution operator and would get the same result as you by application of fundamental properties of delta functions. EDIT: in your solution, it should be '$j$' not '$-j$' for the last two terms.